# Read & Post Local storage image from url as byte or stream

Tags: cordova, apache-cordova

I am saving album images and camera images in local storage and retriving it later. Also i want to upload those images as bytes content to my http request. How can i achieve this.

```
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                console.log("read success");
                console.log(evt.target.result);
            };
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(imageFileURI);

        data.append("image", fileReader);


        fileReader.readAsDataURL(imageFileURI);
```

This is what i found but i dont get bytes or binary array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at cordovaFileTransfer?

cordovaFileTransfer.upload(API_URL, imageFileURI, uploadOptions)